# Azure Message Routing: JSON message in wrong format

Tags: json, azure, base64, content-type, azure-iot-hub

I'm working with a raspberry pi zero and Python to send and recieve sensor data with Azure IoT. I've already created an endpoint and message routing to the storage container. But when I check the JSON-Files in the container, I've got two problems:

- The file include various general data which i don't need
- My message body is in Base24-format

My message looks like this:

> {"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2021-06-25T13:03:25.7110000Z","Properties":{},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"RaspberryPi","connectionAuthMethod":"{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"637555519600003402","enqueuedTime":"2021-06-25T13:03:25.7110000Z"},"Body":"eyJ0ZW1wZXJhdHVyZSI6IDI4Ljk1LCAicHJlc3N1cmUiOiA5ODEuMDg2Njk1NDU5MzMyNiwgImh1bWlkaXR5IjogNDYuMjE0ODE3NjkyOTEyODgsICJ0aW1lIjogIjIwMjEtMDYtMjUgMTQ6MDM6MjUuNjMxNzk1In0="}

The body included my sensor data in Base64-format. I've already read about contentType = application/JSON and contentEncoding = UTF-8 so that Azure can work with correct JSON files. But where do i apply these settings? When I apply it to the routing query, I get the following error:

> [Routing Query Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXLfh.png) (The server didn't understand your query. Check your query syntax and try again)

I just want to get the body-message in correct JSON Format.

Thank you all for any kind of help! Since it's my first experience with this kind of stuff, I'm a little helpless.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't decode the body when you read the info?

Answer (score 0):

Zero clue if this helps, but here is my code for sending data from Raspberry Pi Python to AWS - Parse Server using base64/JSON. The only reason I use base64 is to send pictures. You should only have to use JSON to send your other data.

```
    import requests
    import random, time
    import math
    import json
    import Adafruit_DHT
    import base64
    from Adafruit_CCS811 import Adafruit_CCS811
    from picamera import PiCamera
    from time import sleep


    DHT_SENSOR = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
    DHT_PIN =4
    ccs =  Adafruit_CCS811()
    camera = PiCamera()


    while True:
       time.sleep(5)
       camera.start_preview()
       sleep(5)
       camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg')
       camera.stop_preview()
       with open('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg', 'rb') as binary_file:
           binary_file_data = binary_file.read()
           base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_file_data)
           base64_message = base64_encoded_data.decode('utf-8')
       humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_SENSOR, DHT_PIN)
       ccs.readData()
       parseServer = {
           "temp": temperature,
           "humid": humidity,
           "co2": ccs.geteCO2(),
           "pic": base64_message
       }
       resultJSON = json.dumps(parseServer)

       headers = {
       'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'myappID',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }

       data = resultJSON
       response = 
       requests.put('http://1.11.111.1111/parse/classes/Gamefuck/TIuRnws3Ag', 
       headers=headers, data=data)

       print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll check it during the weekend. Have you also changed something on the azure endpoint or message routing?

Comment: I haven't messed with azure. I'm using AWC EC2 parse server. But when I print my "data" vs sending it to the network, I do not get extra information you were talking about.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=application-level

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Python SDK for Azure IoT, sending the message as UTF-8 encoded JSON is as easy as setting two properties on your message object. There is a good example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/send_message.py)

```py
msg.content_encoding = "utf-8"
msg.content_type = "application/json"
```

Furthermore, you don't need to change anything in IoT Hub for this. This message setting is a prerequisite to be able to do message routing based on the body of the message.